# VSTO can not installed with Visual Studio 2022 Installer

Tags: visual-studio, installation, vsto, visual-studio-2022, visual-studio-installer

I rent absolutely free

```
Edition Windows 10 Pro
Version 20H2
Installed on    ‎2/‎7/‎2023
OS build    19042.1706
Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.4170.0
```

With Excel installed and Activated by hosting provider

```
Microsoft Office LTSC Professional Plus 2021
Version 2108 (build 14332.20447 Click-to-Run)
```

Than I try to install to this new machine VS 2022 community from official site

Unfortunately VSTO tools is impossible to install, I see a lot of times the same error

[VSTO installation Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9g5tU.png)

What I need to do? I need VSTO.

I receive advice to download firstly and install after full download. In this case I have this error.

[Something going wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eryPU.png)

What going wrong I don't understand. This VM placed to datacenter in Germany with good connection and preinstalled and activated legal copy Windows 10 and Excel.

Comment: It may be possible to skip & continue and later `Modify` the installation and select VSTO. [Screenshot here](https://i.imgur.com/GRJ0Z8j.png)

Comment: Looks like internet connection issue. The file on your screenshot with error message is actually available. Try again later maybe?

Comment: @Nikolay, It's not look as internet connection problem. (1) I receive this issue more than one time. (2) This is not my local computer, this is remote computer on datacenter. Wrong connection from datacenter on Germany to California? Not really... And other packages downloaded and installed succesfuly.

Comment: Hm. Hard to tell then. But it seems that it is "just you, not everyone". If it is a datacenter, can't you get a VM with Visual Studio pre-installed instead (there is a wide choice of ready-to-go images on azure fore example)? The "problematic" package is actually GIT, so you can try downloading and installing it yourself (i.e. follow the link it complains about, download it manually and then install). It could also be a good way to check that the link is actually accessible.

Comment: @Nikolay, I receive VM with preinstalled and activated Excel. Any other packages, except VSTO installed sucessfuly. Issue present exactly with VSTO packages.

Comment: So have you tried to open that problematic link yourself? I mean something like copying it from the installer error message and pasting in the browser address line. On that machine.

Comment: @Nikolay, Where is problematic link? I see only screen - something went wrong, I have add this screen to question.

Comment: The problematic link is right on your first screenshot "VSTO installation Error" (first line), "after 9 attempts, there was a probelm downloading file from `https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2168274`. Could it be that your provider is blocking your from downloading this file? Try downloading it manually, with browser. Or maybe your anti-virus software is blocking this download.

Comment: The link refers to GIT version management tool, it's the most commonly used version management tool and is safe to download. Somehow, this download seems to get blocked (by something) on the computer where you run the installation.

Comment: Just as an idea, the link above actually redirects you to `https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.39.1.windows.1/Git-2.39.1-64-bit.exe`. Maybe you have github blocked on the target computer?

Comment: From the error `something went wrong`, you could try to search for git in individual components and select [Git for windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/865ZR.png). Click Modify. This will install GitV2. In the lower left corner of your picture, there's a button `View Logs`.Could you provide the full logs information to investigate this issue?

Comment: Yes,@Nikolay, you are right, this computer going to any site except Github. It can going to Github but extremely slow, after 30 second I see only a couple text string from Github site, even without CSS styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably you are dealing with a connection problem. You may try to repair your VS installation at a later point of time.

You may consider downloading a local installation package, select the `Download all`, then install option in the dropdown at the bottom of the Workloads tab of the Visual Studio Installer. The purpose of this feature is to frontload the downloading of the Visual Studio packages onto the same computer that you plan on eventually installing Visual Studio on. By downloading the packages locally first, you can then safely disconnect from the internet before you install Visual Studio.

[image: download all, then install]

Also you can download the installer locally by using a command line. And only then you can launch the installer for the Visual Studio, so you will not face with such problems. Read more about that in the [Create an offline installation package of Visual Studio for local installation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/create-an-offline-installation-of-visual-studio?view=vs-2022) article.

Comment: Connection to what? To MS server in California? This is screen from remote server on datacenter in Germany. And I have more than one times this issue. And other packages downloaded and installed succesfuly.

Comment: Did you try downloading the offline installer? Does it work correctly?

Comment: For you advice I change method of installation - from Install while downloading to Download all, then install. In this case I see new error - something went wrong. I have add this screen to question. What exactly going wrong I don't see any information.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the logs to find out what exactly happens on your machine?

Comment: I don't understand a reason, but this computer can not going to Github, very-very slow, even CSS file is not possible to read from Github domain. Any other site working cool and fast.